# Connect to windows remote server using java and modify some files?

Tags: java, windows, remote-access

Hi I have been doing some manual tasks which consume some of my time and I want to automate it the tasks are:

1. Connecting to remote windows server using mstsc command and restarting some services.
2. Connecting to remote windows server and modifying the files, checking the modifications and then again reverting the changes when the changes are tested.

I want to know whether I can achieve a one click solution for this scenario by writing some code in java and reducing the manual time.

Or is there any other solution for the same which can be generic and could be implemented on other servers too.

The steps for the solution to cover would be:

1. Connect to remote machine using username and password.
2. Restarting the services from the code or just executing a batch file for the same which could be lying in some folder on the same machine.
3. Modifying some files on the remote machine.

Comment: Why not use already existing tools, such as powershell, etc.? example - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/10/13/powertip-use-poweshell-to-start-service-on-remote-machine/

Comment: Hey @OldProgrammer thanks a lot for opening a new window. I read some points and I think that I can achieve things by using powershell.
I will revert once I explore more regarding powershell.